# =?UTF-8?B??= in Emails sent via php mail problem

Tags: php, javascript, html, email

I have a website, and in the "Contact" section I have a form which users may fill in to contact me.
The form is a simple form which action is a php page.

The php code:

```
$to = "email@domain.com";

$name=$_POST['name']; // sender name
$email=$_POST['email']; // sender email
$tel= $_POST['tel']; // sender tel
$subject=$_POST['subject']; // subject CHOSEN FROM DROPLIST, ALL TESTED
$text=$_POST['text']; // Message from sender
$text.="\n\nTel:".$tel; // Added to message to show me the telephone nr to the sender at bottom of message

$headers="MIME-Version: 1.0"."\n";
$headers.="Content-type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8"."\n";
$headers.="From: $name <$email>"."\n";

mail($to, '=?UTF-8?B?'.base64_encode($subject).'?=', $text, $headers, '-fno-reply@domain.com');
```

Could somebody please tell me why this works most of the time, but sometimes I receive email whith no text and the subject line showing

```
=?UTF-8?B??=
```

I use outlook express, and I have read this [System.Net.Mail and =?utf-8?B?XXXXX.... Headers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/454833/system-net-mail-and-utf-8bxxxxx-headers)
but it didn't help.

The problem is not in Outlook, because when I log in to the actual mailprogram where I fetch the POP3 emails from, the email looks the same.

When I right click in Outlook and chose "message source" then there is no "From" information.

Ex, a good message should look like this:

```
Subject: =?UTF-8?B?w5Z2cmlndA==?=
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8
From: John Doe
```

However, the ones with problem looks like this:

```
Subject: =?UTF-8?B??=
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8
From:
```

As if the information has been lost somewhere.

You should know also that I have a VPS, which I manage myself.
I use postfix as an emailserver, if thats got anything to do with it.
But then again, why does it work sometimes?

Also another thing that I have noticed is that sometimes special characters are not shown correctly (by both Outlook and the webmail).

For instance, the name "Björkman" in swedish is shown like `BjÃ¶rkman`, but again, only sometimes.

I hope anybody knows something about this problem, because it is very hard to track down for me atleast.

If you need more input let me know.

Thanks

Comment: Read the accepted answer of the question you show in your question. `your subject contains relatively many characters outside the ASCII range.` It means that your server _can't_ send mail with subject with some accent or/and special char. Did you try with a subject like "Hello world" ?

Comment: As the question says, this happens only sometimes. The subject line is one amongst 5 options in a drop list, all works and are tested. I believe that is not the problem. This problem happens sometimes only.

Comment: you may also try asking this on serverfault, as it might have something to do with the email server

Comment: Have you tried adding `accept-charset="utf-8"` as an attribute to the contact form? Have you been able to reproduce this yourself? If not, which browsers have you tried? If you have, what does `var_dump($_POST)` say? Could you perhaps add a hidden field with the visitor's user agent string to the form so you can see if specific browsers cause problems?

Comment: Be aware that even though the subject is chosen via a dropdown. This doesn't mean someone can submit the same POST variables without a value to the same php-page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When looking at PHP [mail()](http://php.net/mail), I see another line breaking: shouldn't you use `\r\n` as line endings?

And that `BjÃ¶rkman` example looks very much like your mail is not recognized as UTF-8 encoded.