# subject displays in encoding format while sending long subject

Tags: c#, .net, outlook

I am sending mail to outlook using System.Net.Mail
Here code i used,

```
msg.From = new MailAddress("stagingsupport@syncfusion.com");
msg.IsBodyHtml = true;
msg.Body = "Some text";                        
msg.To.Add("karthike@syncfusion.com");
msg.Subject = "[Enterprise Priority] - Customer Incident 85172 for Karthik (108269) velusamys@syncfusion.com : Custom function called from within an AND function results in error - Syncfusion Website Team Test I – Created";
```

I am getting the subject like =?utf-8?B?W0VudGVycHJpc2UgU...

I dint give any non ascii character in subject but i comes in encoded form.I refered the following link,i cant get the solution that much,

[System.Net.Mail and =?utf-8?B?XXXXX.... Headers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/454833/system-net-mail-and-utf-8bxxxxx-headers)

What i have to follow to get the subject come correct decoded form?

Comment: What's wrong with that? That's one of the ways to represent email headers, looks correct to me.

Answer (score 0):

You have to set UTF8 encoding.

```
msg.SubjectEncoding= System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
```

Comment: Set the same encoding for BodyEncoding too.

Comment: i did get it.Is there any bug in outlook?

Comment: No not at all. It doesn't matter. Your program uses .net API.

Comment: outlook is not decoding the encoded subject line because it exceeds the maximum length limit. what i look to say is,encoded subject will be truncated,outlook not able to decode the truncated encoded subject. I think this is the problem here.Could you give me the solution?